# Non blocking getch()

Tags: c++, getch

I'm trying to make Tetris game in standard console. I need non-blocking getch(), so the blocks can fall without pressing any key. It would be nice to have function that returns -1 if no key pressed, otherwise the key code.

Comment: You'll need to have an infinite loop and handle _keypress_ events inside of it.

Comment: @RobKennedy - dupe assumes using ncurses

Comment: @kittyPL, what OS and compiler are you using? As you might infer from the duplicate vote, `getch()` is a non-standard function. Functions with that name are provided in the MS Windows API and in a Unix library called "curses". Other than coincidentally sharing a name, those functions are wholly unrelated.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question about **non-blocking** getch and the duplicate is about **blocking** getch (the OP wanted it to be blocking where it was non-blocking due to incorrect usage of the library, which is hardly a solution).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's operating system specific but your library probably has a function called kbhit() or similar that will do this

Answer (score 20):

This is exactly what you wanted:

```
int getch_noblock() {
    if (_kbhit())
        return _getch();
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Basically `kbhit()` does the job of determining if a key is pressed.

Assumes Windows and Microsoft Visual C++.

Comment: Just to mention that you would need #include <conio.h> in order to use _kbhit()